# How to display JSP with WildFly

Tags: jsp, wildfly

When I was using JBoss 7.1.1 I could display a JSP page doing something like that :

```
@WebServlet("/path")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

But when I do the same thing with WildFly 9.0.2 it's not working and I have the following error :

```
15:55:40,264 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher 60] (default task-2) PathInfo: /WEB-INF/login.jsp
15:55:40,269 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler 135] (default task-2) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/myapp-web/WEB-INF/login.jsp
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:112) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.11.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.11.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.11.Final.jar:]
    ...
```

My web.xml file is almost empty :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
</web-app>
```

How to do it working with WildFly 9 ?

Comment: Works for me. Did you put login.jsp in you WEB-INF directory and that it's getting copied into your WEB-INF deployment directory?

Comment: Yes my mistake. I have a class which extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` with the annotation `javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath`. And the value of the annotation was `"/"`. That's why I could't reached my JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was my mistake. In the following class, the annotation value was `"/"` instead of `"/ws"` for example:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/ws")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are redirecting a client/user to a login prompt for your restful service. The way I have seen this done is to use the BASIC authentication configuration in the web.xml file. I recently ported dukes-forest to wildfly and it uses that setup. You are welcome to [look at it](https://github.com/karlnicholas/dukes-forest) if you want. The service is a [payment service](https://github.com/karlnicholas/dukes-forest/tree/master/dukes-payment) and it is setup to use a database to hold users. The database configuration is in the [entities project](https://github.com/karlnicholas/dukes-forest/tree/master/entities), and the client is in the [main dukes-store](https://github.com/karlnicholas/dukes-forest/tree/master/dukes-store) project in the [PaymentHandler.java](https://github.com/karlnicholas/dukes-forest/blob/master/dukes-store/src/main/java/com/forest/handlers/PaymentHandler.java) class. Hope this helps.